# Can we save file from virtual pc

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I want to know if i install virtual pc win 10 and save a file for example ms word file. After creating the file in virtual pc win 10 can i bring that file or access in my original pc. And from which virtual pc software can be done. How can it is possible. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: if that virtual pc has access to the internet, then of course you can send files via e-mail, upload to clouds ...

Comment: what  virtualisation software are you using? (VMware, Oracle virtualbox etc)?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat still not yet install if i get the correct software to what i need that software i can install so i have posted the question after installing and saving can i access in my original pc. I have microsoft pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtualbox supports drag and drop between the virtual machine and the host.

Comment: really can you tell me how it works.

Comment: And it supports defining a folder for file exchange.

Comment: @ateks You drag the file from a folder (or the desktop) of one machine and drop it on a folder (or the desktop) on the other.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You mean like normal pc how we access drag and drop same with the virtual and original pc we can drag and drop

Comment: @ateks Yes, exactly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 1 more request vitualbox support win 10.

Comment: @ateks Yes, VirtualBox supports Windows 10 as both the [host OS](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#hostossupport) as well as a [guest OS](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#guestossupport).

Answer (score 1):

In VirtualBox you can also set up shared folders - pick a folder on your host and it'll become a shared network folder on the guest (if it's got some virtualbox guest addons installed).

[image: VirtualBox Shared Folders]

And you can also read or convert a virtual hard drive file, to read the files directly without running the guest OS. A web search found this link for Windows [7 Ways To Open Virtual Hard Disk Images For Read And Write Access](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/access-virtual-hard-disks-easily-in-windows-7/) - *Just use 7-zip for reading*
I thought I read somewhere that `mount` in linux can mount them, or may have to convert to RAW first (with `vboxmanage`?).

(I haven't been able to get the file drag & drop into/out of virtualbox to work, nor shared clipboards, for some unknown reason)